# SUM() all results (no group by clause)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm having a strange error. I have SQL code which looks like:

```
SELECT 
    adverse_reaction_type_id,
    SUM(CASE adverse_reaction_type_id WHEN 1 THEN `number` ELSE 0 END ) line, 
    SUM(CASE adverse_reaction_type_id WHEN 2 THEN `number` ELSE 0 END ) drug 
FROM
    core_reports_adverse_reactions, 
    ...
WHERE 
    ...
```

This works fine on my MAMP installation, but doesn't on my remote server. I assume there's a config option somewhere which is stopping it from working.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP
>   columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

I know what the error is telling me, but the problem is that I **don't want** to group by anything. I want to get all results where the where bit (removed above for brevity) matches and then return the `SUM()` of the `number` column (as either `line` or `drug` based on the `CASE` clause).

So essentially, regardless of what is **matched** by the `WHERE` clause all I want to return is **1** row:

```
line | drug
-----------
10   | 32
```

Is there a way around this at all? Or any way I can `GROUP BY nothing` or something?

Comment: Posting as a comment, because it's only a partial answer: this error can only occur if you have the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL-mode enabled (see [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)), so the difference between your MAMP installation and your remote server might just be that you don't have that SQL-mode enabled on your MAMP installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `GROUP` BY a constant on the table where you run the `SELECT`.

For example `GROUP BY NULL`:

```
mysql> select SUM(CASE WHEN product_id = 0 THEN -1 ELSE product_id END) AS sumprod, SUM(quantity) AS sumquant FROM orders GROUP BY NULL;
+---------+----------+
| sumprod | sumquant |
+---------+----------+
|       4 |        8 |
+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select version();
+-------------+
| version()   |
+-------------+
| 5.5.25a-log |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But usually this error means that there is **at least one column** which is *not* grouped.

It might be that the production version of MySQL is taken aback by your use of a CASE within the aggregate function.

Comment: ah, i see what you mean, and that makes the error make sense. I had actually cut down the HUGE sql query to make it more readable and had removed some "select" columns thinking they werent relevant. I've reedited the question, but now I've taken that `id` field out of my main query and it works fine! :) thanks!

Comment: It is not any constant. It can't be an integer.

Comment: True; but that's because integers here are considered indexes into `SELECT`'s column fields, not 'true' integers. If you had a table ( user varchar(20), score integer), `SELECT user, SUM(score) FROM points GROUP BY 1` would be accepted -- and would group by user. `GROUP BY 2` would be rejected (cannot aggregate by an aggregate function), `GROUP BY 3` would be refused (there is no third column).